# Delete a database row using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using a PHP function to format any 2D PHP array to HTML table, In that table I need to add a delete button in each row, So when the user clicks the delete button jQuery should take particular fields ( 3 fields ) and submit in a php file and it should give the response without reloading the page, I have several dynamic tables in same PHP files, So i have used $table_name as the form ID to differentiate the FORMS, and In the del.php ( Where my form get submitted ) I decide which table should I look up to delete the row using the PRIMARY KEY. My Problem is Do I have to create Forms Within each table to do this task? or can I simply put some  fields and submit the form using jQuery?

Any help would be much appreciable .

```
function formatArrayToTable($foo, $deletable = 0, $restaurant_id ='', $table_name = '') {
  //open table
  echo '<table class="imagetable">';

  // our control variable
  $first = true;

  foreach($foo as $key1 => $val1) {
    //if first time through, we need a header row
    if($first){
      echo '<tr>';
      foreach($val1 as $key2 => $value2) {
        echo '<th>'.$key2.'</th>';
      }

      if($deletable) {
        echo "<th>'Delete'</th>";
      }

      echo '</tr>';

      //set control to false
      $first = false;
    }

    echo '<tr>';

    foreach($val1 as $key2 => $value2) {
      echo '<td>'.$value2.'</td>';
    }

    if($deletable) {
      $primary = $val1["id"];

      echo "<input type='hidden' name='table_name' value='{$table_name}' />";
      echo "<input type='hidden' name='restaurant_id' value='{$restaurant_id}' />";
      echo "<td><input class='delete_class' type=\"button\" name=\"delete_id\" value={$primary} onclick='SubmitForm($table_name)'/></td>" ;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
}
```

My Javascript Function

```
function SubmitForm(formId){
  var message = "";
  $("#"+formId+" input").each(function() {
    message += $(this).attr("name");
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "del.php",
    data: message,
    success: 
      function() {
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
          .append("<p>Entry is Deleted </p>")
          .hide()
      }
  });
}
```

-Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to ask if you can remove items from a DB using just jQuery. Conventionally, as far as I know, this is not doable, because your DB is server-side and your jQuery is client-side. That being said, I am sure some kook has created a library for it. Despite that, to answer your actual question:

You need to know how you can use jQuery to simulate direct removal of a table row from a DB table. Here is a rough example of your needed jQuery, a sample output of your current php function, and something that should live in del.php to handle the actual delete.

**Example Table**

Quick notes. Add thead and tbody tags to help browsers with the displaying. Remove the `onclick=""` bit, you are using jQuery, so just add your callbacks with a JavaScript block. Make sure your code adds the `.submittable' class (or other descriptive name) to your table. You *could* wrap the whole table in a form, then use a plugin like [jquery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to handle submissions of each form, but that seems like overkill for only handful of fields, so I will explain how to do it with the raw materials.

```
<table class="imagetable submittable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>file</th>
      <th>meta</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='table_name' value='secret_image_table' />
        <input type='hidden' name='restaurant_id' value='123' />
        <input class='delete_class' type='button' name='delete_id' value="Delete" />
      </td>
      <td>Silly Cat Image</td>
      <td>yarny-cat.jpg</td>
      <td>{"submitter":"De Zéro Toxin"}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery code block**

It is a terrible idea to submit your table name from any client-side form, ajax or otherwise. That is super sensitive information, and any programmer/hacker could use that knowledge to their advantage when trying to attack your site. Despite that, I don't know the usage of this, so it may be fine in your setting. Still bad practice though.

```
// any time any element with the 'delete_class' on it is clicked, then
$(document).on('click', '.delete_class', function(e) {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');

  var data = {
    table: $('[name="table_name"]').val(),
    id: $('[name="restaurant_id"]').val()
  };

  $.post('del.php', data, function(r) {
    // do some special stuff with your json response 'r' (javascript object)
    ...

    // do what you showed us you are doing, displaying a message
    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
      .append("<p>Entry is Deleted </p>")
      .hide();

    // remove the row, since it is gone from the DB
    row.remove();
  }, 'json');
});
```

**del.php**

Again, table_name on submission = bad-idea. Horse beaten.

```
// define a delete function that accepts a table name an id

// define some functions to sanitize your $_POST data, to prevent SQL Injection.
// run said functions before you get to this point

// json response function, since you said you want a response from your js
function respond($data) {
  echo @json_encode($data);
  exit;
}

if (empty($_POST)) respond(array('error' => 'Invalid request')); 

$table_name = $_POST['table_name'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$response = deleteRecord($table_name, $id);

if ($response == $what_you_expect_on_a_successful_delete) {
  // create a response message, in associative array form
  $message = array('success' => true);

  // add some other information to your message as needed
  $message['sideNote'] = 'I like waffles.';

  // respond with your message
  respond($message);
}

// if we got this far your delete failed
respond(array('error' => 'Request Failed'));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use jQuery to delete a row in a DB directly, you will need to establish a DB connection from jQuery.  Not such a bright idea.  Instead, you should have a server side function to do the job and call that function using an AJAX call from jQuery.